# Android testing and Fragment IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, testing, fragment, android-testing

I have an Android app that I'd like to test using the Android testing framework.

I setup everything correctly and when I run the tests I get:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(16003): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0700aa for fragment HomeFragment{41766600 #0 id=0x7f0700aa}
E/AndroidRuntime(16003):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:864)
E/AndroidRuntime(16003):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
E/AndroidRuntime(16003):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
E/AndroidRuntime(16003):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
E/AndroidRuntime(16003):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:505)
E/AndroidRuntime(16003):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1133)
E/AndroidRuntime(16003):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4475)
E/AndroidRuntime(16003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1929)
```

I have an activity called `HomeActivity` that `onCreate()` performs a `FragmentTransaction` to add the `HomeFragment`. My `HomeActivity` layout has a container view which I use to perform various fragment transactions.

I inflate the view of the HomeFragment during onCreateView().

If I remove the transaction then test pass but obviously thats not what I want.

Thoughts?

Comment: It looks like you're referencing some view that Android considers to be invalid when the transaction happens - perhaps for the fragment container? Trace `0x7f0700aa` back into your `R` file and have a look at what the id's name is for more clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out it was a library dependency problem generating different R file for the test project and different R file for the target project.